# codeignitier cart only hold 10 items even store the session in database

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery, cart

i've seen many question about codeignitier cart in this forum
and the problem solved only with changing the config file

but i still face that problem

i have changes the config file like this

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']          = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']          = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']      = 600;
```

and in database, ci_sessions table, user_data column, the item can be store more than 10 items

```
s:11:"total_items";i:12;s:10:"cart_total";i:420000;}}
```

and the code for showing cart item

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>{
    echo $items['id'];
    echo $items['image'];
    ....
}
```

when i check with firebug, i still got an error about overlimit cookies size

is there anything else i should check to fixed my problem??

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you getting an actual error somewhere, or is your code just doing something you're not expecting, or what?

Comment: it show an error in firebug everytime i make a request to show the cart item and the error message is about cookies overlimit ..

Answer (score 0):

You got hit by maximum cookie length, since CodeIgniter uses the session cookie to store the session data by default. Cookies can hold about 4093 bye data per domain (so if you have 2 cookies they sum size cant go above that).

If you make CI use the database for session store (as you do now) then should reduce the cookie size. CI will only put [session metadata in the cooke](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L291-294), and userdata into the database. Check the your CI version, maybe you are on an outdated version.

Alternatively you can check out Session library replacements like [NativeSession](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session), this code will mimic the same API but uses php's built in session functionality so you can use file or memcached backed storage easily as well.

Comment: i've tried to use a different version .. but it still the same .. the cart item store in database correctly, but only for 10 item, when i store the 11th item, all of the item (in database) is replace by this 11th item ..

Comment: @lemone, this replacing behavior sounds really strange, i think this might done by your application code, not the libraries. Try disabling the session encryption, so you can see what's inside the session cookie. With `sess_use_database` enabled you should should only see something like this: `a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"...";s:10:"ip_address";s:9:"...";s:10:"user_agent";s:7:"Firefox";s:13:"last_activity";i:...;}ec61fc3e45cb86d20a7c2dd1680e998b` In your question the `"total_items";i:12` says that there is 12 elements in the cart. Maybe you are adding items with duplicate ids?